# Export hundreds of email (.PST) and convert into PDF - Possible?

Tags: pdf, conversion, microsoft-outlook-2003

Would it be possible to extract/archive emails from MS Outlook 2003 and then, have them all converted into PDF files? The only thing I know that could work is doing that process one email by one... Such a long shot.

Please let me know if you guys know a trick or a software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acrobat Pro X and above will create a single indexed, searchable .pdf file of exported emails.